# micrometer tracing brave + rest template / web client

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, brave, micrometer-tracing

I am trying to propagate traceId from one service to another that is called by rest template / web client

I'd expect that the traceId will be the same but in reality the new one is generated.

service 1:

```java
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080");
    }
```

simpe call to service-2:

```java
webClient.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

I have these dependencies in both services:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I got the same behaviour with rest template.
According to documentation the `traceparent` header should be propagated, but its not.
I am using spring boot 3.0.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are builing a WebClient from scratch, no autoconfiguration is taking place. You should change the WebClient bean method and inject a WebClient.Builder.

```java
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        return builder.baseUrl("....").build();
    }
```